# Relation between differential geometry and differential geodesy

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesy

I am not exactly clear on what are the differences between differential geometry and differential geodesy. Are principles in differential geometry used in differential geodesy ?

It appears that differential geodesy would be one of the applications of differential geometry but I do not have a reference that says as much.

Could somebody clarify for a beginning student like myself ?

**EDIT**

From this link [Differential geodesy](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a254951.pdf)

It appears that it is indeed the applications of differential geometric techniques to the curves and surfaces that occur in geodesy.

Comment: Your edit appears to answer the question.